# C++ compiler error with stringbuf / ifstream

Tags: c++, file-io, compiler-errors

I cannot understand why my compiler (MSVC++2010) doesn't like this code:

```
    // get_sum(filename as c-string) returns sum from file
    int get_sum(const char* const s) {
        stringbuf bill_buf;
        ifstream bill_file;
        bill_file.open(s);
        bill_file.get(bill_buf, '\0');  // read whole file
        bill_file.close();
        return get_sum_from_string(bill_buf.str());
}
```

I get these errors (I translated them from German to English and give the correct line numbers for the code excerpt without leading comment):

1. Error   1   error C2079: 'bill_buf' uses undefined class 'std::basic_stringbuf<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>' (Line 2)
2. Error   2   error C2664: 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::get(_Elem *,std::streamsize)': Conversion of parameter 1 from 'int' to 'char *' not possible (Line 5)
3. Error   3   error C2228: To the left of ".str" there must be a class/structure/union. (Line 7)

Has anyone got an idea what's going on there? Thanks a lot! (If anyone has got a better idea how to quickly get the whole file contents into a string, I'd also appreciate it)

Comment: Errors 2 and 3 are side-effects of #1.  Did you specify 'using std'?  Do you have the correct header file for stringbuf?

Comment: you're missing an include file that defines stringbug... Now which one was it.

Comment: That's right, I just did `include <streambuf>`. Thanks, all of you! All these headers!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing an include. Here's your code, this time without using `streambuf`:

```
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<iterator>

int get_sum(const char* const s) {
    std::ifstream bill_file(s);
    std::string contents((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(bill_file)),
                         std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    return get_sum_from_string(contents);
}
```

Comment: `istreambuf_iterator`?! There are some things I hadn't even dreamed of =) How do people find these things? Did you study textbooks on the standard library?

Comment: The internet is not just for p0rn, my friend. :)

Comment: Meh. Well, even though others were quicker in making it compile, I think I'm going for this variant because it's so concise ... With only these two lines left, I even consider putting it all in one method. Oh, actually, follow up question: might this string c'tor throw an exception?

Comment: Also, the constructor of `std::ifstream` takes a `const char*` for a filename, and it then opens the file for reading. This means there's no need to call `open()` on the file object if I use the constructor. The destructor of `std::ifstream` closes the stream, so there's no need to call `close()`. This is RAII in all its glory; it simplifies code magnificently and you should get in the habit of using it whenever you need to acquire resources of any kind (memory, files, a database connection, a glass of Tia Maria with swiss bonbons).

Comment: Yes, the string constructor may throw. It reads a file, and Bad Things can happen while you're reading a file. Like hard-disk failure, like the file vanishing all of a sudden while reading it, all sorts of things. But if you don't know what to do with the exception then don't try to catch it; just let it seamlessly propagate to the caller. The same applies for the `std::ifstream` constructor. It may throw too if, for example, it can't open the file for some reason. But if you don't know what to do about it then don't catch anything.

Comment: Hm, actually, this does NOT compile! Now it says: `Error 1 error C2664: 'ProjektRenate::get_sum_from_string': Conversion of parameter 1 from 'std::string (__cdecl *)(std::istreambuf_iterator<_Elem,_Traits>,std::istreambuf_iterator<_Elem,_Traits> (__cdecl *)(void))' to 'std::string' not possible` .... (in the line calling `get_sum_from_string()`, whose signature is simply `int get_sum_from_string(string s)`. ????

Comment: @Felix you're right. Fixed. The problem was the so-called _C++'s Most Vexing Parse_. The statement `std::string contents(iter(), iter());` confuses the C++ compiler as it looks like a declaration of a function which takes two iterators and returns a string. According to C++ rules if something looks like a function declaration then that's what it is. Then, I tried to pass that function declaration (in effect, a pointer to a function) to the `get_sum_from_string()` function, which expects a string parameter and not a function pointer.

Comment: The solution to this is to wrap one of the parameters to the constructor of the string object with parentheses. A function declaration can't have any of its parameters wrapped with parentheses, but a constructor-call may. This makes the C++ compiler then believe that it's not a function declaration but an instantiation of an object through a constructor-call.

Comment: Wow, thanks. And I just learned why my `Thing thing()` calls never work, while I thought it was OK to call a constructor that way. * g *

Answer (score 4):

For #1, you probably forgot to `#include <sstream>` and only have a forward declaration from some other header in scope. #2 and #3 are follow-up errors, don't mind them, fix #1 first and go on.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to `#include <sstream>`.

Answer (score 0):

1) In your header file (.h) you should specify "using namespace std". Otherwise, all your stream operations/variables etc have to start with 'std::'

2) Have you included the right headers? You should add

```
#include <sstream>
```